# Can't understand a piece of C++ code with perfect forwarding and ellipses

Tags: c++

I can't understand what does the following piece of C++ code does:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void print(Ts &&... ts)
{
    ns::logger{ (print(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), ns::s{})... };
}
```

I see that there's perfect forwarding with variadic arguments, but what is happening in the line below precisely?

My guess is that an object of type `ns::logger` is being uniform initialized with a series of values but I'm not sure which ones.. is that `...` a folding expression?

Comment: Thanks, and will `ns::s{}` be added after each `print` returned object?

Comment: What is the return type of `print`?

Comment: @Holt `void`, I thought it returned something different.. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ns::logger` is being initialized with a list of expressions `(print(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), ns::s{})`, one for each element in `ts`.

Each expression, in turn, uses [a comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). It calls `print(std::forward<Ts>(ts))` and discards its result (if any). Then it constructs `ns::s{}`, and that object becomes the result of the comma operator.

The net result is roughly equivalent to this pseudocode:

```
print(std::forward<Ts_1>(ts_1));
print(std::forward<Ts_2>(ts_2));
...
print(std::forward<Ts_N>(ts_N));

ns::logger{ns::s{}, ns::s{}, ... /* repeated N times */};
```

Comment: … and if `logger` and `s` are trivial types, this is a common workaround to get the effect of a statement pack expansion. The confusing bit does nothing; it's only a little dance to provide a suitable context for `print()...` which is the interesting part.